# Regex with unknown character length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, signatures

Simple question for you folks.
Sorry that I have to ask it.

On my website, I want to use signatures at "random" places in my text. The problem is, There could be multiple DIFFERENT signatures in this given string.

The signature code is `~~USERNAME~~`

So anything like

```
~~timtj~~
~~foobar~~
~~totallylongusername~~
~~I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5~~
```

I have tried using `preg_match` for this, with no success. I understand that the third parameter is used to store the matches, but I can not properly get a match because of the format.

Should I not use `preg_match`, or am I just not able to use signatures in this manner?

Comment: With the help of @Shankar and @max-m, using `preg_match_all` ended up being the best resort. Using this, it returns an array with 2 subarrays, `[0]` and `[1]`. With these arrays, you can use something similar to my code `return(str_replace($match[0],array_map("getsignature",$match[1]),$mystring));` where `getsignature` is a returnable function that searches a database or string for the username given by variable `$1` (ex: `function getsignature($username){`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of `preg_match_all` and with this modified `regex`

```
preg_match_all('/~~(.*?)~~/', $str, $matches);
```

[image]

### The code...

```
<?php
$str="~~I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5~~";
preg_match_all('/~~(.*?)~~/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5
)
```

Comment: I like the looks of it, however, when I run this with `$str="Here is my signature: ~~timtj~~"`, it returns an array, with sublevel arrays containing `~~timtj~~` AND `timtj`. I would like it to only return the one without the tildes.

Comment: @timtj, I have showed you the results `without the tildes` as expected.  As you can see there is no `tildes` in the output.

Comment: I see now. Upon closer inspection, I have omitted the `[1]` from your example, and with it, it works beautifully. Accepted answer and upvote. Thanks for expressing your knowledge in a simple way!

Answer (score 4):

This should work, but usernames mustn't contain `~~`

`preg_match_all('!~~(.*?)~~!', $str, $matches);`

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~~timtj~~
            [1] => ~~foobar~~
            [2] => ~~totallylongusername~~
            [3] => ~~I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5~~
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => timtj
            [1] => foobar
            [2] => totallylongusername
            [3] => I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5
        )
)
```

The first sub array contains the complete matched strings and the other sub arrays contain the matched groups.

---

You could change the order by using the flag `PREG_SET_ORDER`, see http://php.net/preg_match_all#refsect1-function.preg-match-all-parameters

```
<?php
$str = "~~timtj~~ ~~foobar~~ ~~totallylongusername~~ ~~I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5~~";
preg_match_all("!~~(.*?)~~!", str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

This code produces the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~~timtj~~
            [1] => timtj
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~~foobar~~
            [1] => foobar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~~totallylongusername~~
            [1] => totallylongusername
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~~I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5~~
            [1] => I-d0n't-us3-pr0p3r-ch@r@ct3r5
        )
)
```

Comment: This code works well. Not sure what the difference is in relation to having `!` at the beginning and end of the exp as opposed to `/`, but I am willing to accept that this code works

Comment: @timtj, They are just the delimiters for an regular expression you can even add `@` !! :)

Comment: @timtj you can use any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character as delimiter, see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Just when you think you know enough to get the job done, PHP always has something for someone to learn.